# Space Not Being Generated in HTML Output?

Tags: functions, formatting

I'm using a code called custom_link_pages to generate my multiple page post links, but I'm getting a space between my page numbers and previous link, but my next  link is missing the same space.  These need to be spaced equally so I would like to either add the necessary space or remove all spaces.

For reference to what I'm talking about, view line 281 at: http://themeforward.com/demo2/?p=1813&page=2

I am assuming this could be from the custom code in my functions:

```
    // Custom Next/Previous Page
add_filter('wp_link_pages_args', 'wp_link_pages_args_prevnext_add');
/**
 * Add prev and next links to a numbered link list
 */
function wp_link_pages_args_prevnext_add($args)
{
    global $page, $numpages, $more, $pagenow;

    if (!$args['next_or_number'] == 'next_and_number')
        return $args; # exit early

    $args['next_or_number'] = 'number'; # keep numbering for the main part
    if (!$more)
        return $args; # exit early

    if($page-1) # there is a previous page
        $args['before'] .= _wp_link_page($page-1)
        . $args['link_before']. $args['previouspagelink'] . $args['link_after'] . '</a>'
    ;

    if ($page<$numpages) # there is a next page
        $args['after'] = _wp_link_page($page+1)
        . $args['link_before'] . $args['nextpagelink'] . $args['link_after'] . '</a>'
        . $args['after']
    ;

    return $args;
}
```

How I grab that code:

```
<?php
custom_link_pages(array(
    'before' => '<div class="pagelinks">' . __(''),
    'after' => '</div>',
    'next_or_number' => 'next_and_number', # activate parameter overloading
    'nextpagelink' => __('Next'),
    'previouspagelink' => __('Previous'),
    'pagelink' => '%',
    'echo' => 1 )
);
?>
```

Comment: What is this `__('')` thingy?

Comment: @toscho it's for localization.

Comment: @BandonRandon A localized space? Really? ;)

Comment: @toscho, Apparently, I don't see no harm in it. That would allow for removal or addition of space using a translation file.

Comment: Without context it is problably one of the worst strings to translate ever. Plus, there are not that much different spaces in different languages.

Comment: @toscho, true true, I actually didn't notice the space until you pointed it out. This must be the space before the content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may sound stupid but why not just add the space in your function? There are several places to do it:

`'nextpagelink' => __(' Next')`

`$args['link_before'] . ' ' . $args['nextpagelink'] . $args['link_after'] . '</a>'`